# Generate video from self shots

Tags: opencv, video, image-processing, photo, face-detection

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post such a question. But maybe, someone can help me.

I took a lot of photos from a person the last few month. The pictures are all front-faced pictures, with different lightnings, one time the face is closer to the camera, then one time farer away etc. Now I want to create a movie with all the pictures, to show some progress. But before I begin to manually correct the photos (fix lightning, make all faces the same size, rotate the faces a little bit...), and put them in Premiere, I was wondering if there is some kind of software to achieve this. It could be a program, script, library... I read a little bit about open cv, but maybe there is already something out there.

Comment: And I don't understand the downvote. Any reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be possible  with OpenCV ,

As your requirement the first thing is

**Lighting adjustment**

OpenCV has an entire documentation about [Changing the contrast and brightness of an image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html). In another way you  adjust the contrast with [histogram equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html). For this you need to convert your RGB image to HSV and apply [equalizeHist()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#equalizehist) to the V(value) channel.

**OpenCV Resize**

For resizing you can use OpenCV [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function

Here is a piece of code how to do this

```
Mat src = imread(image.jpg);
Mat dst;
resize(src, dst, Size(640, 480), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC); // resize to 640X480 resolution
```

**Rotation**

For rotation you can use [Affine Transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html)

**Video Writing**

OpenCV has  [VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) class to write video using various frame rate,codec, resolution etc..

Here is the source code for writing video using series of image, assuming your images with names 0.jpg,1.jpg,2.jpg.....

```
int main()
{

  VideoWriter writer;
  writer.open("out.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),15,Size(640,480),true);//Initialize video writer. The resolution should be same as source image
  if(!writer.isOpened()){
    cout<<"Cannot write video..!!!"<<endl;
    return -1;
    }

  char name[10];
  int i=0;
  while(1){
  sprintf(name,"%d.jpg",i++);
  Mat src=imread(name,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   if (src.empty()){ 
     cout<<"No source found...."<<endl;
     break;
    }
  writer.write(src);
  imshow("src", src);
  waitKey(0);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cool, thanks! Is it possible to detect the shape of the face, and based on this, rotate, scale etc. the pictures?

Comment: I think possible, you may look on these link http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#face-recognition